# Rails Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, csrf, csrf-protection, curb

I've succesfully created new record by using post method api like this (Using `Curl::PostField`)

```
curl_post_fields = [
    Curl::PostField.content('first_name', first_name),
    Curl::PostField.content('last_name', last_name),]

  contact = Curl::Easy.http_post("#{ENV['API_V1_URL']}/contacts", *curl_post_fields)
  contact.ssl_verify_peer = false
  contact.http_auth_types = :basic
  contact.username = ENV['API_V1_USERNAME']
  contact.password = ENV['API_V1_PASSWORD']
  contact.perform
  response = JSON.parse(contact.body_str)
```

but when i was updating record via patch like this one (using json request parameter):

```
contact = Curl.patch("#{ENV['API_V1_URL']}/contacts/#{qontak_id}",{:email => email, :gender_id => 8})
contact.ssl_verify_peer = false
contact.http_auth_types = :basic
contact.username = ENV['API_V1_USERNAME']
contact.password = ENV['API_V1_PASSWORD']
contact.perform
response = JSON.parse(contact.body_str)
```

i got some errors from server

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

`Filter chain halted as :authenticate rendered or redirected`

also i have turn off csrf `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`

it is possible that using `Curl::PostField` is automatically including `csrf token` or are there any similar way like `Curl::Postfield` in `patch or put method` ?

Comment: hi guys i still stuck on this, any help please ?

Answer (score -1):

You might try explicitly skipping the token filter.

Within your API controller:

`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:put]
respond_to :json`

Make sure to restart your server as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is that makes the API less secure ?

Comment: I was wondering there is another way without turn off csrf or skip token verification ?

Comment: You could add your own api_key and require it in the application controller. This is a common problem that I ran into just the other day, and I think it's related to Rails 5. Are you running an API only application?

Comment: too insecure solution